# Weird colors after installing KDE Plasma [on Chrome browser]

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome, kde, plasma, plasma-5

I have set my dev environment ready to work on my projects and noticed that all is much more "glowy", (unclicked) links are purple instead of blue, facebook blue colors are now purple, ubuntu forum orange bar is very bright, ect'. (does not happen in firefox)

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: This flag was removed in Chrome 62, and it's no longer possible to disable color-correct rendering. See https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/698347**

not sure if this is the best solution for this, but I disabled:
`Color correct rendering` in `chrome://flags/` and now colors look good.

Comment: for me, it worked to set the `Force color Profile` to `sRGB` also from the flags.